# Number of possible values of $4x-z$ if $x+y+z=20$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, integers

Given that $x, y,z$ are non negative integers such that $x+y+z=20$. If $S$ is the set of all possible values of $4x-z$.Find $n(S)$.

My try:
By stars and bars number of non negative integer solutions of $x+y+z=20$ is $\binom{22}{2}=210$

Among these $210$ ordered triplets of $(x,y,z)$ we need to find number of possible values taken by $4x-z$.

Obviously the least value taken by $4x-z$ is $-20$ when $x=0,z=20$.
The next value taken by $4x-z$ is $-19$ when $x=0,z=19$ and so on.

So once we fix $x=0$ ,since $z$ varies from $[0,20]$ number of values taken by $4x-z$ is $21$.

But when we fix $x=1$, we get some overlaps. For example when $x=1,z=18$ we have $4x-z=-14$ and this value has already been counted in the previous case when $x=0,z=14$.

So any way to count total number of values taken by $4x-z$ excluding overlaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can count the total possible unique values of $4x-z$ by summing the size of the following 5 mutually disjoint sets of values:

- Non-positive values: corresponds to $x=0$, there are $21$ such values of $4x-z$ from $-20$ to $0$, corresponding to $z=0,1,2,\ldots , 20$.
- Positive values of form $\equiv 0 \pmod 4$: corresponds to $z=0$ and $x=1,2,\ldots, 20$, there are 20 such values.
- Positive values of form $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$: corresponds to $z=1$ and $x=1,2,\ldots, 19$, there are 19 such values.
- Positive values of form $\equiv 2 \pmod 4$: corresponds to $z=2$ and $x=1,2,\ldots, 18$, there are 18 such values.
- Positive values of form $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$: corresponds to $z=3$ and $x=1,2,\ldots, 17$, there are 17 such values.

Generalizing the above mod 4 cases, we have the following mutually disjoint sets of values:

- Non-positive values: corresponds to $x=0$, there are $21$ such values of $4x-z$ from $-20$ to $0$, corresponding to $z=0,1,2,\ldots, 20$.
- Positive values of form $\equiv -k \pmod 4$: corresponds to $z=k$ and $x=1,2,\ldots, (20-k)$, there are $20-k$ such values of $4x-z$, for $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$.

Hence, the total number of distinct values of $4x-z$ will be $=21+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{3}(20-k)=21+80-6=95$

Comment: For positive values of $4x-z$ such that $4x-z \equiv 1\pmod{4}$, wont it be $z=3$ and $x=1,2,3...17$

Comment: Yeah you are right, the it should be $\equiv -3 \pmod 4$, for $z=3$, the result remains the same though.

Answer (score 2):

For a given value of $x$, $z$ can range from $0$ up to $20-x$. This means that
$$D_a := \{4a-z \mid a + y + z = 20\} = \{5a-20, 5a-19, \ldots, 4a\}$$
(note that $5a-20 \leq 4a$ when $0 \leq x \leq 20$) where $a$ is fixed. Notice also that $4a \geq 5(a+1)-20$ for $a \leq 15$. This means that $D_a$ and $D_{a+1}$ overlap for $a \leq 15$. As a result, we find that
$$D_0 \cup D_1 \cup D_2 \cup \cdots \cup D_{16} = \{5 \cdot 0 - 20, \ldots, 4 \cdot 16\} = \{-20, \ldots, 64\}$$
For $a \geq 17$, $D_a$ is disjoint from $D_{a-1}$ and $D_{a+1}$. This means that
\begin{align}
n(\{4x-z \mid x + y + z = 20\}) &= n(D_0 \cup D_1 \cup \cdots \cup D_{20}) \\
&= n(D_0 \cup \cdots \cup D_{16}) + n(D_{17}) + n(D_{18}) + n(D_{19}) + n(D_{20}) \\
&= 85 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = \boxed{95}
\end{align}

Comment: Correct, checked independently with my C++ program.

Comment: @User123 You can post your program as an answer

Comment: I think that he wants an elegant solution. Otherwise, OK, I can try (and not receive downvotes from pure mathematicians : )

Answer (score 1):

Well the very least $x$ can be is $0$ and if so, you can have $z$ be any value from $0$ to $20$ inclusive (by letting $y = 20-z$). SO all (integer) values from $-20$ to $0$ are possible but no smaller are possible.

Now we just have to find all possible positive values.

Every positive integer is a multiple of $4$ minus either $0, 1,2$ or $3$ so if we set $z= 0,1,2$ or $3$ we can get set $x$ to any value from $1$ to $17$ (by letting $y = 20 - x-z$) so get all values up to $4\cdot 17 - 0= 68$.  So all values between $-20$ to $68$ inclusive are possible.

Now we just have to find all possible higher values.

And we can do those one by one.  If $n = 4x -z > 68$ and $z \ge 0$ then $x > 17$ so as $0\le x \le 20$ we can have $x = 18,19, 20$.

If $x = 18$ then $z = 20 -18 -y = 2-z$ so $z$ can be $0,1$ or $2$.  So that allows $6\cdot 18 - 0,1,2$ or $72,71,70$ but not $69$.

If $x = 19$ then $z =1-y$ and $z$ can be $0$ or $1$ so that allows $76,75$ (but not $74$ or $73$.

And $x = 20$ then $z=0$ and we have $80$ is possible but $79,78,77$ are not.

So the total number is $-20,....1$ and $0$ and $1.... 68$ and then $3$ and $2$ and $1$ more.  For a total of $20 + 1 + 68 + 3+ 2 + 1= 95$ values.

=====

Or more systematic.

$x$ con range from $0$ to $20$ and $z$ from $0$ to $20$ so $4x-z$ can run from $4\cdot 0 -20=-20$ to $4\cdot 20 - 0=80$

The times $n = 4a - b$ are *not* possible is if $a + b>20$

As $4a - b= 4(a+1)- (b+4)$ so if we have $n$ not possible so $a + b > 20$ we must also have either $(a+1)+(b-4)>20$ or $a+1 > 20$ or $b-4 < 0$.  So wolog we can assume that if $n=4a-b$ is impossible that we are assuming that $0\le b < 4$. And therefore $a+ b >20$ and $a > 20-b$.

For $a=20$ there are $3$ impossible values values for $b$.  For $a = 19$ there are $2$ impossible values.  For $a=18$ there is $1$. ANd for $a \le 17$ there are none.

So all values between $-20...,80$ are possible except for $1+2+3 = 6$ impossible values.

So there are $101-6 = 95$ possible values.

Answer (score 1):

As @SomeGuy said, you can post programs, too.

Here is mine (in C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int n = 5000;
    std::unordered_set<int> vec = {};
    for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= n - x; y++)
        {
            int value = 5 * x - n + y;
            vec.insert(value);
        }
    }
    std::cout << vec.size();
}
```

The output is 95. It is incredibly efficient because of unordered_set.

Comment: You can eliminate the condition-checking `if (z >= 0)` by changing the upper bound (terminating condition) of the 2nd loop to `y <= 20 - x`

Comment: @SandipanDey Yeah, found that while optimizing code. Also, I added unordered_set – the program is incredibly fast now for not too big numbers.

Comment: Also, since you are using `set` data structure, `if (vec.find(value) == vec.end())` check is redundant too. A single line of code inside the 2nd loop `vec.insert(5*x-20+y)` should do the job.

Comment: @SandipanDey Nice, around 40% faster.

Comment: Any good books to learn this coding?

Comment: I don't know... We should ask some more experienced, but I think you can use https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/default.asp as an introduction to the language (to get to know what you can do), but if you want to go to the intermediate phase, there are some good books out there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list. But this is only for C++ (fast and my favourite). You can also learn Python (slower, but according to many people fun).or Java (also for graphics application and Android).

Comment: @Umesh Shankar for C++, Bjarne Stroustrup is the best one, little advanced though